# How to get the width and height of a character in usr coordinates

Tags: r

How can I get the *width* and *height* of a character in `usr` coordinates? I found something on [R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/99a/0870.htm), but that appears not to make it completely clear. I assumed that

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1))
h <- par()$cxy
rect(-h[1]/2, -h[2]/2, h[1]/2, h[2]/2)
text(0,0,"M")
```

[image]

would be the answer but the rectangle is slightly too big. Additionally I want the size also to respect different `cex` values. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered an answer in the `par` docu:

> **cxy**
>
> R.O.; size of default character (width, height) in user coordinate
>   units. par("cxy") is par("cin")/par("pin") scaled to user coordinates.
>   Note that c(strwidth(ch), strheight(ch)) for a given string ch is
>   usually much more precise.

Using `strwidth`  and `strheight` instead of `par()$cxy` gives much better results.

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1))
h <- c(strwidth("M"), strheight("M"))
rect(-h[1]/2, -h[2]/2, h[1]/2, h[2]/2)
text(0,0,"M")
```

[image]